# Sort HTML elements by data-attribute

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have the following markup:

```
<ul>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="jeans">Bottoms</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="tops">Shirt</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="jeans">Jeans</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="jeans">Shorts</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="tops">Hoodie</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="accesories">Sunglasses</li>
</ul>
```

The elements can have different group names in the `data-category-group` attribute. I want to be able to sort the elements so that the elements with the group of jeans will all come after each other in the DOM.

I had an idea to try to solve this by turning the HTML collection into an array and then sort them. But its does not seem to be able to work that way.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var categoryItems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category-group]");
var categoryItemsArray = Array.from(categoryItems)

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = categoryItemsArray;

function myFunction() {
    categoryItemsArray.sort();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = categoryItemsArray;
}
```

How could this be achieved?

Checkout a codepen here: https://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/PBGrPZ

Comment: Here you go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyaexR?editors=1010

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `Array#sort`, just pass it a function that checks the `data-category-group` property (using [`String#localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)):

```js
var categoryItems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category-group]");
var categoryItemsArray = Array.from(categoryItems);

let sorted = categoryItemsArray.sort(sorter);

function sorter(a,b) {
    return a.dataset.categoryGroup.localeCompare(b.dataset.categoryGroup); // sorts based on alphabetical order
}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => sorted.forEach(e => document.querySelector("#demo").appendChild(e));
```

```html
<ul id="demo">
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="jeans">Bottoms</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="tops">Shirt</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="jeans">Jeans</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="jeans">Shorts</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="tops">Hoodie</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="accesories">Sunglasses</li>
</ul>


<button>Sort Elements</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with `sort` method on an array and then append back elements to  `ul`.

```js
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");
let li = ul.querySelectorAll("li");

let sorted = Array.from(li).sort((a, b) => {
  return (b.dataset.categoryGroup == 'jeans') - (a.dataset.categoryGroup == 'jeans')
})

ul.innerHTML = "";
sorted.forEach(e => ul.appendChild(e))
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="jeans">Bottoms</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="tops">Shirt</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="jeans">Jeans</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="jeans">Shorts</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="tops">Hoodie</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-category-group="accesories">Sunglasses</li>
</ul>
```